# Expand table rows based on column value

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table with two columns; `EVENT_DATE` date and `RANG` number the first column holds a date for an event while the second column is for the period of that event. here is a sample of data

```
| EVENT_DATE | RANG |
|------------|------|
| 03/01/2015 |    1 |
| 09/04/2015 |    3 |
| 15/10/2015 |    2 |
```

is there any way to expand the `EVENT_DATE` by increment it based on the `RANG` value, so the output will be like,

```
| EVENT_DATE |
|------------|
| 03/01/2015 |
| 04/01/2015 |

| 09/04/2015 |
| 10/04/2015 |
| 11/04/2015 |
| 12/04/2015 |

| 15/10/2015 |
| 16/10/2015 |
| 17/10/2015 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

```
select to_char(event_date + (l - 1),'dd/mm/yyyy') from tab1 t
left outer join (
  select level l from dual
  connect by level <= (select max(rang) + 1 from tab1)
) on l <= rang + 1
order by event_date, 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/27fef0/15)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select (t.event_date + t2.value) as event_date
from t, (select rownum -1 as value from all_objects) t2
where t2.value <= t.rang
order by 1 asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer. Assume `Event1` is your table

```
with tmp as
(select MAX(RANG) s FROM Event1)
,rec as (
    select 0 num
    union all
    select num+1 from rec where num < (select s from tmp))
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, r.num, e.Event_Date) Result from rec r join Event1 e on r.num <= e.RANG
ORDER BY DATEADD(DAY, r.num, e.Event_Date)
```